# Stop multiple field filling with v-model?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm pretty new to Vue.js and while I've figured most of the problems I'm hitting out, I can't get my head around this one.

I'm displaying a list of posts based on API output, and want to have a comments box for each post. Posting to the API is working fine and it adds it without a problem, but because I'm using the same v-model for each input in the loop any text entered is replicated throughout all other matching inputs due to the binding.

```
                    <div class="row" v-if="">
                        <div class="col-md-11">
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" value="" title=""
                                   placeholder="Add comments here.." v-model="note.note">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: -1.5rem" v-on:click="addNote(task.id)">Add Comment</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JS:

```
  addNote: function (id) {
        if (this.note.note) {
            Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('value');

            this.$http.post('api/note/create/' + id, this.note).then(function (response) {
                this.fetchTaskList();
            });

        } 
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Is there a different directive I should be using? Or is there another way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `index` in `v-for` and then binding each box to the notes `comment` like so:

```
<!-- use index, so we know where we are in the loop -->
<div v-for="(note, index) in notes">
  {{ note.note }}
   <!-- Bind to the comment at the given index -->
  <input v-model="notes[index].comment" />
</div>
```

Now you just need to set that up in data:

```
data: {
  notes: [
    {note: 'note 1', comment: ''},
    {note: 'note 2', comment: ''},
    {note: 'note 3', comment: ''}
  ]
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/efxzmq9s/